# Monitoring Shape based region vs. Starting the Significant-Change Location Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, core-location

I am currently working on a location-based reminder app and I am trying to understand iOS 4/5 location services and some of the core location features. Since I want to use geo-fences of different sizes (user can choose the size), I was wondering if I need to combine Significant-Change Location Service with region monitoring or if it is enough to simply use Region Monitoring by itself to make those reminders go off.

As far as I understand Significant-change Location Service, my app would only get a location update if I switch cell towers. Would that mean that in case the geo-fence was somewhere in between that the reminder would not go off?

Compared to that how does Region Monitoring work, other than of course monitoring regions? Will the reminder always go off or are there any blind spots? If so, does DistanceFilter play a role here?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case should be covered with region monitoring.

> As far as I understand Significant-change Location Service, my app would only get a location update if I switch cell towers. Would that mean that in case the geo-fence was somewhere in between that the reminder would not go off?

This might happen and is an edge case that you would have to cover. I really depends on many things, location accuracy being one of them. You would definitely have to test that one thoroughly.

> Compared to that how does Region Monitoring work, other than of course monitoring regions? Will the reminder always go off or are there any blind spots? If so, does DistanceFilter play a role here?

Last time I checked (> 10 months) region monitoring wasn't always accurate enough. It worked but used cell towers more than the current position to monitor for regions. What that means: Don't rely on region changes alone and dont' expect them to be accurate to the meter.